# How to fix "OSError: Initializing from file failed" error in Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to load the well-known `Iris` dataset using seaborn using the following code and get `OSError: Initializing from file failed` error.

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

**NOTE:** I am working on a virtual environment on Jupyter notebook, thought maybe it might have something to do with the error.

Comment: Are you able to do `pd.read_csv('path/to/iris.csv')`? You can get the iris dataset from the seaborn repo: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data to test this.

Comment: Well I had to move on so I did the following, which I knew would work:
```import pandas as pd```
```iris = pd.read_csv('datasets/Iris.csv')```
But I didn't really understand why I ended up having that error using ```Seaborn```.